# Use of the definite article by Hemingway in "For Whom the Bell Tolls", in a way that doesn't seem to mimic Spanish grammar

Tags: definite-articles, literature, spanish

I am not a native English speaker, but I've been studying English for a couple of decades now... And recently I decided to read "For Whom the Bell Tolls". I know that in this book Hemingway writes in a different way, trying to mimic Spanish grammar in English. But in Chapter 19, one Spanish character (Pablo) says:

> "But I believe that the Pilar can divine events (...)"

So Hemingway used the definite article before someone's name. But as far as I know this is not how one would speak in Spanish: *"Pero yo creo que Pilar puede adivinar (...)"*. There is no definite article there, and it doesn't seem to be something that one would do in English either. It only sounds natural to me in Portuguese: *"Creio que a Pilar pode adivinhar (...)"* -- the "a"  before Pilar is the definite article in Portuguese. And even in Portuguese, it would be perfectly normal to ommit the article.

So, what is it that I did not get? Is it acceptable to use "the" before someone's name in English? (I have never seen that before)

Comment: Do you live in the US?  Have you ever heard someone say "the Donald"?

Comment: Hemmingway called his boat **Pilar**. Someone wrote this paper titled [*Can’t You Hear He Speaks Spanish? The Theme of Language in Ernest Hemingway’s For Whom the Bell Tolls*](chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://lib.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/002/212/963/RUG01-002212963_2015_0001_AC.pdf) wherein on page 57 he specifically addresses the usages **the Pilar**   and  **the  Anselmo**, saying *These phrases seem faulty in English, but **they create an impression of the Spanish language.** Moreover, they suggest the guerrilleros’ respect for one another and their noble character.*

Comment: Try Chapter 31 where 4 out 8 *Pilar*s are *the Pilar*.  My guess is that her full given name was something like *María del Pilar* and Hemingway uses *the Pilar* as a play on this when emphasising the oracle  nature of her statements.

Comment: I see...  It just didn't sound like natural in Spanish to me (my native language is Portuguese, and I have been to Spanish-speaking countries quite often). I know that in Latin languages the definite article can be used before a proper noun, but in that phrase it did sound a little strange. But after reading your comments it begins to make more sense -- thank you! And the book really is an impressive work!

Comment: Some dialects and registers of Spanish do indeed do the same thing as Portuguese does here but it is considered quite informal. This corresponds to using *that* in English, as in *that George*. It dates from proto-Romance with Latin demonstratives. This might be a good question for  [spanish.se] and you are of course always welcome on [portuguese.se].

Answer (score 5):

"***...the Pilar...***" sounds perfectly Spanglish to me.  It's common in Spanish to use the definite article when referring to famous people (women especially).  This usage is also used affectionately/satirically about friends and family who may be acting haughtily/grandly...

In the Spanish link below, the example is given of a political candidate whose full name is *Perú Inga Zapata*.  She is referred to in discussions/the press as 'La Perú'.  In the banner newspaper headline - "***Y como esta La Perú***" ("*And How Is Peru*") - readers' attention is grabbed because Peru, the country, is masculine (El Perú).

The English link also suggests how English achieves a similar affect.

http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/y-como-esta-la-peru/

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Spanish-speakers-use-a-la-in-front-of-a-name-of-a-girl-I-e-La-Monica-La-Maria-La-Charlotte-What-is-the-intended-effect

Comment: You might want to add that it is more common among the less educated classes.

Comment: Ah -- that's it. I have heard womens' names without "La" too often, maybe (it seems that it's more usual to not include the article). The second link that you included mentions that *"Colocar artículos definidos (la y el) delante de los nombres propios suele ser característico en determinados ambientes o estilos y tienen, generalmente, un valor expresivo o más bien afectivo"* -- that's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there has to be any hauteur to use the definite article with a person's name.  But there is a great place to check -- http://spanish.stackexchange.com/